# WordPress Display User's Avatar not Showing

Tags: php, wordpress, avatar

I am making a wordpress site now, and I just inserted an HTML block into my sidebar.  I want to to serve 2 functions.
1. If the user isn't signed in, I want it to display a login block.  (working)
2. If the user is signed in, I want it to display their avatar.  (not working)
I looked up the get_avatar function on the wordpress site, and this is what I found.  But it doesn't show anything...

My code:

```
[logged_out][login][/logged_out]
[logged_in]
<?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    echo get_avatar(ID, 128 );
?>
[/logged_in]
```

My question, is this because it is an HTML block, and it won't support PHP, or is something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Define a shortcode in your functions.php
http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Return `<img src="avatar_src" />` from shortcode definition
Then you can use that shortcode in your text widget and add this filter to make it working

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode